# Limit BitTorrent Sync connections to a specific network

Tags: network, firewalls, access-control, file-access, bittorrent

Is it possible to limit BitTorrent Sync connections to a a specific network using the client software? Right now the closest I can come up with would be IP limitations imposed on *each client* using a firewall. This seems like it would work fine, except for if *any* client somehow ventures outside those firewall restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Linux, iptables has a match called "owner" where you can apply certain rules based off the UID or GID of the process sending the data.

For instance:

- Put the IP's or CIDR network addresses in a file (one entry per line)
- Create a new user called **btsync**
- Run the following:

  ```
  #/bin/bash

  RESTRICTED_IP_FILE="/some/file"

  sudo iptables -N btsync_filter
  sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner btsync -j btsync_filter

  while read ip; do 
      [[ -n "$ip" ]] && sudo iptables -A btsync_filter -d $ip -j DROP
  done < $RESTRICTED_IP_FILE

  sudo -u btsync btsync
  ```

This will run **btsync** as the user **btsync** and all packets from that process that are going to a restricted IP will be dropped.